# UrlFetchApp (Google Scripts) for HTML requests with Token to Zendesk

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api, zendesk

here is my script->

```
var url = "https://mycompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/1234/tickets.json";
var TOKEN = "sean@seansean.com/token:vss0keykeykey";  
var options =
{
 "method" : "GET",
 "contentType" : "application/json",
 "headers" : {
   "Authorization" : 'Bearer ' + TOKEN  
 },
};

var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

right now I am getting a access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed or invalid for other reasons, however if I do a curl right from the command line it works fine....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Access tokens have [limited lifetimes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) which is correct from a security standpoint. Google provides service accounts that allow server to server communications. Your application prepares to make authorized API calls by using the service account's credentials to request an access token from the OAuth 2.0 auth server.

For more information, you may visit OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [ZenDesk documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction#security-and-authentication), your `TOKEN` looks like input to what you'd use in *API Token* authentication, which uses HTTP Basic Authentication, yet your Authorization header includes the word *Bearer* which suggests it is an OAuth access token (which it isn't).

Take a look at the documentation and see whether you can indeed use Basic Authentication (the documentation lists some restrictions around 2-factor authentication, relating to how your account is set up).

If you can use Basic Authentication, then you need to form your token like this:

```
// Form the Basic Authentication header - needs Base64 encoding as cUrl would do.
var TOKEN = Utilities.base64Encode("sean@seansean.com/token:vss0keykeykey"); 

var options = {
 "method" : "GET",
 "contentType" : "application/json",
 "headers" : {
   // No need for the "Bearer" prefix
   "Authorization" : TOKEN  
 }
};
```